# Creating a new QuickFix acceptor application

Tags: c#, .net, quickfix, fix-protocol

I'm trying to create a FIX acceptor application using QuickFix in C#... I'm having a strange problem I can't quite seem to get around... When trying to create a new ThreadedSocketAcceptor, the constructor is throwing a FormatException saying "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime." I'm not sure whats causing this as the only date times in my configuration file are session times... Here is a snippet of my code and the corresponding acceptor config file:

```
        SessionSettings settings = new SessionSettings(SettingInfo);
        application = new TFAcceptorApplication();   

        application.DataArrived += new DataArrivedEventHandler(DataArrivedEvent);    

        FileStoreFactory storeFactory = new FileStoreFactory( settings );
        FileLogFactory logFactory = new FileLogFactory( settings );
        DefaultMessageFactory messageFactory = new DefaultMessageFactory();

        acceptor = new ThreadedSocketAcceptor(application, storeFactory, settings, logFactory, messageFactory);    
        acceptor.Start();
```

Config File:

```
[DEFAULT]
ConnectionType=acceptor
SocketAcceptPort=9999
SocketReuseAddress=Y
FileStorePath=store
FileLogPath=log

[SESSION]
BeginString=FIX.4.4
SenderCompID=MySenderCompId
TargetCompID=MyTargetCompId
UseDataDictionary=N
DataDictionary=FIX44.xml
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=23:59:00
```

Nothing I try seems to work, the exception gets thrown every time I reach that code. Any chance anyone has come across a similar problem and knows what can be causing it?

Thanks for taking the time to read my question,
Cheers!

Edit: Stack Trace -

```
mscorlib.dll!System.DateTimeParse.ParseExact(string s, string format, System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles style) + 0x6b bytes 
    mscorlib.dll!System.DateTime.ParseExact(string s, string format, System.IFormatProvider provider, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles style) + 0x32 bytes   
    QuickFix.dll!QuickFix.Util.UtcDateTimeSerializer.FromString(string s) + 0x5c bytes  
    QuickFix.dll!QuickFix.FileStore.InitializeSessionCreateTime() + 0xf1 bytes  
    QuickFix.dll!QuickFix.FileStore.open() + 0x29 bytes 
    QuickFix.dll!QuickFix.FileStore.FileStore(string path, QuickFix.SessionID sessionID) + 0x187 bytes  
    QuickFix.dll!QuickFix.FileStoreFactory.Create(QuickFix.SessionID sessionID) + 0x5c bytes    
    QuickFix.dll!QuickFix.Session.Session(QuickFix.IApplication app, QuickFix.IMessageStoreFactory storeFactory, QuickFix.SessionID sessID, QuickFix.DataDictionaryProvider dataDictProvider, QuickFix.SessionSchedule sessionSchedule, int heartBtInt, QuickFix.ILogFactory logFactory, QuickFix.IMessageFactory msgFactory, string senderDefaultApplVerID) + 0x229 bytes  
    QuickFix.dll!QuickFix.SessionFactory.Create(QuickFix.SessionID sessionID, QuickFix.Dictionary settings) + 0x432 bytes   
    QuickFix.dll!QuickFix.ThreadedSocketAcceptor.CreateSessions(QuickFix.SessionSettings settings) + 0x110 bytes    
    QuickFix.dll!QuickFix.ThreadedSocketAcceptor.ThreadedSocketAcceptor(QuickFix.SessionFactory sessionFactory, QuickFix.SessionSettings settings) + 0xd1 bytes 
    QuickFix.dll!QuickFix.ThreadedSocketAcceptor.ThreadedSocketAcceptor(QuickFix.IApplication application, QuickFix.IMessageStoreFactory storeFactory, QuickFix.SessionSettings settings, QuickFix.ILogFactory logFactory, QuickFix.IMessageFactory messageFactory) + 0x4b bytes    
>   ExecutionReportGenerator.exe!ExecutionReportGenerator.ExecutionForm.StartConnection() Line 194 + 0x3d bytes C#
    ExecutionReportGenerator.exe!ExecutionReportGenerator.ExecutionForm.ConnectButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) Line 87 + 0x8 bytes  C#
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(System.EventArgs e) + 0x70 bytes  
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(System.EventArgs e) + 0x4a bytes
```

Comment: Updated OP with stack trace

Comment: I was able to use IronPython to start an acceptor using the code you provided;  I used the string form of SessionSettings. Perhaps you are inadvertently loading a config file from a different directory that lacks the timestamps?